# Fancytree jQuery plugin - select node

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

I have difficulties in selecting a given node from fancytree plugin.

So, I have tried something like:

```
$("#tree").fancytree("getTree").visit(function(node){
    node.select(n);
});
```

where "n" is any number representing the node id, but it doesn'work, even if the select() function exists in documentation

Could someone help?

Comment: Could you provide a sample fiddle in order to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Sadly, I can't reproduce it.. I struggled to find something useful for selecting a node dynamically but there is no example at all..

Answer (score 16):

```
var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");
var node = tree.getNodeByKey(n);
node.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: Maybe you also need this `node.setActive(true);`.

Comment: It would seem that as of version 2.25 of fancytree, you have to BOTH do a node.setSelected(true) and a node.setActive(true) to make the tree show a selected node as actually selected.